# List all non-stop flights between any European city and city X?

Tags: online-resources, airlines, international-travel, routes, flight-search-engines

My friend was asking "from which European cities can you fly non-stop to Mumbai?"

Similarly I'd like to know all cities in Europe with non-stops to Hong Kong.

(Note too that ideally it would be better to know "dailies"... since once a week etc kind of sucks.)

The only way I know to do this currently:if you go to the online live departures board for an airport, say Zurich, and if you look through a couple of day's worth, you will indeed, discover, pretty much all the non-stop flights from that city!  This is not ideal, so someone may have a better answer.

So, the best way to find this info?  All the non-stop possibilities from X to which European cities?

Comment: How about looking at the airport's _arrival_ board instead.

Comment: The Wikipedia article for the corresponding city's airport is usually pretty accurate.

Comment: Yes, but the arrivals board will give you the flight numbers and arrival times of exactly the flights you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, your question title and the body of the question say two different things. In one you appear to be interested in flights _originating from_ a specific city, and in the other you appear to be interested in flights _arriving at_ a particular city. ("I'd like to know all cities in Europe with non-stops to HK.") I saw one and missed the other. Sorry.

Comment: LHR, AMS, BRU, FRA, MUC, CDG, MXP, ZRH & IST :-) https://www.flightconnections.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Google. It invented an awesome service for searching flights.

Just type in a google search - 'flights from mumbai' and it will return you a list of non-stop flights from mumbai. If you want to find all flights to Mumbai - print 'flights to mumbai'.

[image]

---

For anyone googling here, Google has unfortunately changed the above a little bit since this screenshot; however it's still a fairly amazing facility.

Comment: This answer does not work anymore. I get nothing in searching *flights from helsinki*.

Comment: In my Google it still working

Comment: it is not working for me either - my guess is it depends on the country you are based in. However in any case this post has been closed as a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17180/32134, @MikkaRin would you consider moving your answer from here to there, by posting a new answer there. You can do so easily by clicking `edit` to your answer here, copying the "source code" and pasting it in the answer field of the other Q. That would be amazing. I'd leave this post as is.

Comment: Note that it now works **within Google's new "flights" system.**  It's very easy to find.   Just enter from .. some city.  **And then select Nonstop**.  It will then show you precisely all flights direct to/from that city.

Answer (score 7):

[OpenFlights](http://openflights.org) can give you a scrollable, zoomable map of all routes from any airport.  Sample for Tokyo:

[image]

Here's the direct link for Mumbai: http://openflights.org/airport/BOM

Click to "list" icon next to "227 routes" to see them all, or click on any airport to see what flies there.

Note that Google counts cities, while OpenFlights counts airline routes, so. LHR-BOM is 1 for Google but 4 for OpenFlights (because you can fly on BA, Virgin, Air India, or Jet; plus an AA codeshare, but that's not counted).

Disclaimer: I maintain OpenFlights, but it's a free service.

A close-up example of flights from BOM:

[image]

Comment: Dear jpat - it's **amazing** that's your site.  Amazing!! May I ask (1) where does the data come from, how compete/reliable is it usually?  (2) Looking at the example image I pasted in. (a) are all the flights shown from BOM nonstop (ie, single legs)? (b) notice the 2 flights ->MUC: are they **dailies**, or? can one filter for dailies only?  what does the 'date' column represent on the table at bottom?  What a site, thanks.

Comment: Data comes from Airline Route Mapper, see http://openflights.org/data.html.  Only non-stop flights are shown, and all I know is that those routes are flown at least once a week; see http://openflights.org/blog/2009/06/26/route-mapping-the-world/.  In your screenshot, the LH flight is marked as a codeshare, which means the only *actual* airline metal on the route is AI.  Date is irrelevant here, it's used when recording your own flights (the primary purpose of the site).