# Resource to find regular flights between given cities

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

Is there a search engine to find regular service flights between cities ? Given two cities, airline optional, I'd like to see a list of flight numbers and their departure/arrival times.
Unlike regular searches, I'm not interested in prices/purchasing and I'd like to see all flights available even if the earliest departure has already past.

---

Context: A friend is flying into town today from Calgary, but I don't know when. I happen to know it's Air Canada so I found the routes and flight numbers on their website, but assuming I didn't, where would I find this information (besides asking her for the flight number obviously :) ?

Comment: The airports' websites usually have an arrival board, usually going back a few hours.

Comment: Be sure to [**GO HERE**](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36470/list-all-non-stop-flights-between-city-x-and-any-european-city) for two awesome answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flight track website such as [flightradar24](http://www.flightradar24.com/) and [flightaware](https://flightaware.com/) provide this information.

Both website provides the aircraft model used for each flights and the actually arrive and departure time.

Although flightradar24 cannot track all flights between 2 cities, it provides actual plane (and [registration code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration)) used for every flight. Flighttrader24 also provides [paid apps for Android, iOS, Mac, windows phone and Windows](http://www.flightradar24.com/apps).

Paid user can access more information.

Answer (score 0):

Airports themselves will often have this information.  For example:
http://www.flydulles.com/iad/arrivals-and-departures
It has a selection to show cities.

On a similar, related note, another portion of the site shows every city with a direct connection.
http://www.flydulles.com/iad/nonstop-destinations