# How can I see all routes flown by a given airline?

Tags: online-resources, airlines, maps

I've been trying to find a tool that could give me a list or map of all the destinations of a certain airline.

Something like this [easyjet's route map](http://www.easyjet.com/en/routemap), but for all airlines.

Comment: @fkraiem: Many airlines are, for some reason, very circumspect about where they fly and how often. All you can do on many airline websites is to search for connections between points that you already suspect they have routes to, but publishing an actual route map (or, God forbid, a full timetable!) definitely seems to have fallen out of fashion.

Comment: (And yes, I would in fact like to know what's the matter with the people who run those airlines).

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17180/is-there-a-tool-to-find-all-nonstop-flights-to-one-destination

Comment: @HenningMakholm when the website is maintained by a third party (outsourced), airline's tend to cancel pages that do not change dynamically and need an actual person to update (eg. data that do not come from an active system, such as Amadeus)..

Comment: Not a real answer, rather an additional chance if nothing else helps: Fly with the airline in question. In their on-board magazines, most airlines have a route map somewhere to "show off" to potential regular customers where you can fly with them.

Answer (score 15):

The interface is a bit inconvenient and it has a limit on the number of routes shown simultaneously, but you can do it on [Kayak's list of airlines](https://www.kayak.com/airlines). Click on an airline and you'll get a map of where it flies. E.g. a map for Easyjet:

[image]

You can then filter by a specific city to get a map of which routes are available there, e.g. for Easyjet in Prague:

[image]

In addition it's possible to show *all* direct flights from a given city, but without an airline filter through their [Routes](https://www.kayak.com/routes/PRG/201607) page:

[image]

Comment: This one is definitely missing quite a few routes EasyJet has to Eastern-Europe

Comment: I made the same discovery as @SztupY, in the first overview map, at least one connection seems missing. When specifying the destination airport that one would turn up. See e.g. in the example above, there is only one connection to Prague in the first image while there are actually plenty in the second one. I guess there is some sorting algo of most popular routes involved.

Comment: @SztupY post updated to reflect this.

Comment: For BA it doesn't show SIN-SYD, BAH-DOH or any flights to the Carribbean. Is it really a limit on the number of routes shown or something else?

Comment: @Berwyn I think it shows the top-20 routes

Comment: There seem to be a lot more than 20. Oh, and no flights to Canada!

Comment: @SztupY@mts Any opinion on the latest two answers? Sorry, three answers

Comment: @Berwyn last chance to award bounty

Comment: TBH, I don't like any of the answers. However, I think Kayak is the only one that doesn't have out of date routes. I suspect airlineroutemapper is using openflights data since it doesn't have SJC-LHR, wikipedia doesn't have routes, and the matall deleted post seems to be openflights too. Although I like MH's answer since I only fly alliances, it's less useful for non-alliance flyers

Answer (score 13):

Between the [Star Alliance route map](http://star-alliance.innosked.com/), the [**one**world route map](http://onw.innosked.com/), and the [SkyTeam route map](http://applications.skyteam.com/routemapper/), you can see the vast majority of existing flights. For any given airline, just choose the map corresponding to its alliance. And since most itineraries will have all segments within the same alliance, you probably will need to use only one of these maps.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this only works for airlines that do belong to an alliance, i.e. not for e.g. Ryanair or Easyjet.

Comment: @mts I wouldn't be caught dead on one of their planes, unless it fell out of the sky on top of me. Maybe that's why I didn't think of them.

Answer (score 11):

You could try [openflights](http://openflights.org/). I'm not sure if the data is complete, but a map for easyjet:

[image]

And Indigo (India LCC):

[image]

Comment: OpenFlights is outdated, as it shows flights which no longer exist (e.g. PRG-TAS).

Answer (score 3):

How about the conveniently named http://www.airlineroutemaps.com/, which has an [impressive list of over 800 airlines](http://www.airlineroutemaps.com/airlines).

Comment: Interesting. I can't see LHR-SJC on BA though.

Comment: I was about to post this as an answer just to find you already had. +1 then. Maybe worth noting their alleged sources: "Airline route maps presented in this site were mainly gathered from airline websites [...]"

Answer (score 2):

I have found Wikipedia a particularly useful resource in this. They usually have a page for say [Easyjet destinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyJet_destinations) and also the pages for airports list where airlines fly from there. It being Wikipedia is not updated automatically but then again, it's Wikipedia so it's reliable... enough.

Comment: That's better than I expected. It has the LHR-SJC route which started a month or two ago on BA

Comment: Actually, as @mts points out, it doesn't have the route, just the destination