# How to find the route map of a given airline?

Tags: airlines, routes, china-eastern

It seems in the old days you could easily find the actual route map (ie: showing the actual city to city nonstop legs they fly) of an airline.

It really seems to me this is becoming hard to find these days.

1. Does anyone know of a current route map for China Eastern?

indeed,

2. is there perhaps a resource for the direct city-city route maps for *all or many* airlines?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17180/is-there-a-tool-to-find-all-nonstop-flights-to-one-destination

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.flightconnections.com/

There's a selector:
Airline: China Eastern (MU)

Comment: Astounding.  Also: astounding.

Comment: +1. with hipmunk.com and ita matrix, my most favorite flight planning tool. Another goodie: you can search by "Alliance". i.e. "one world" or "star alliance" as well

Answer (score 2):

China Eastern Route Map: http://nsg.ceair.com/muovc/public/default_map.htm

Hint: If you can't find it on the official website, Google is always your best friend, especially Google image search.